# Removing Windows XP and installing Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: installation, gnome-terminal

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my laptop. Since I hate Windows, I would also like to install Ubuntu on my desktop. It has two 1TB drives in ntfs (one drive is 1TB partition and other 1TB is C: 500GB partition for Windows XP and f: 500GB for data and programs) and I have searched the FAQ and did not come up with an answer if I would lose my data on ntfs drives or if they would mount.

I am a beginner to Ubuntu and do not know how to use the terminal, but I have been using Windows since early DOS. I am 63 and my memory is slipping. I just want Bill Gates out of my computers. I have a Windows tech charging me now to see why my copy of XP Pro is saying it may be counterfeit, and I know that it is not. $99.00 and he will likely tell me I will have to buy a new key at some price. "Love Ubuntu". Also is there any place that I can get a complete list of commands for use in the terminal for Ubuntu 12.04. Thanks for your kind understanding.

Comment: You don't need to knows ALL the commands, just the most frequently used commands because most of the commands you will NEVER use. So here it is: [50 Most Frequently Used UNIX / Linux Commands (With Examples)](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/11/50-linux-commands/). Since you're going to need this as a reference, I also uploaded a text version of _50 Most Frequently Used UNIX / Linux Commands_ to Ubuntu Pastebin [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6036500/).

Answer (score 1):

You can install Ubuntu over Windows. Ubuntu provides an easy-to-use interface for installing, so there are no terminal commands involved.

You will need a blank CD/DVD and an Ubuntu ISO that you can find at [in here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/thank-you?distro=desktop&bits=64&release=lts)

First, extract the ISO using a live CD creator or extracting it with WinRAR to the CD/DVD and burn the files to it. Restart your computer and boot into the CD/DVD. You have the option to install Ubuntu on the desktop.

Keep in mind that installing Ubuntu over Windows **will delete ALL files** you have so **make sure to back them up**.

Comment: Extracting the ISO is an incorrect advice! The CD/DVD will not work if you do it.

Comment: I definitely back @mikewhatever up in this matter.

Answer (score 0):

There's a complete list of terminal commands here :

http://www.ss64.com/bash/

Comment: I don't think it will be ever possible to have a _complete_ list of commands. Also `bash` is not the only shell available in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't **need** to use the terminal to use Ubuntu. Ever.
2. You can remove Windows and install Ubuntu. You can also install Ubuntu alongside Windows, alas with a little hassle. You can also run Ubuntu from a CD or USB stick. This is not convenient for everyday use, but can give you a feel of the system, plus if something goes wrong the results aren't saved - just reboot. Just choose one and post a question how to do it. Note that this question will have already been asked on the site.
3. The others said about the terminal commands. cmd.exe has 30-ish built-ins. The linux interpreter in Ubuntu has about 2700 when fresh, and more as you install programs. Just go step by step. Learn to do your daily task under Ubuntu, then learn how to do them more conveniently with smarter commands, the process never ends.